# The Fraunhofer Measure

Tags: optics, history

In a well known Maxwell paper he uses the units of wavelength which he calls the Fraunhofer Measure. He states it for the Fraunhofer D and F bands as

$$\lambda_D = 2175 \text{ crazy units} = 589nm$$

$$\lambda_F = 1794 \text{ crazy units} = 486nm$$

So the conversion is:

$$1nm \approx 3.69\text{ crazy units}$$
$$1 \text{ crazy unit} \approx 0.270nm$$

But what is the motivation for this?

Comment: I think the original conversion factor in the question was wrong; I've made an edit fixing it.

Comment: The "crazy unit" is probably a characteristic lattice length scale (between neighboring atoms in a lattice) for a common material, which was easy to compare diffraction experiments with. So all materials were measured relative to this "standard candle" material.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think the reference in my answer below clears it up; the Paris inch was probably more common in those days!

Comment: @JasonDavies oops wrong way round :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is related to the archaic [Paris inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_inch), which is $27.069$mm, i.e. $10^8 \times$ the conversion factor.

Reference: [Scientific Papers Vol 2 1881-1887](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=azQ9AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA503&ots=89VMrCGjTW&dq=%22Fraunhofer%27s%20measure%22%20paris%20inch&pg=PA503#v=onepage&q=%22Fraunhofer%27s%20measure%22%20paris%20inch&f=false), John William Strutt.

Comment: It's from exactly the same area of literature, so it makes sense. Oh, and it says `K` is Mrs Maxwell (`J` is Mr)